# Targeting compound selectors in gulp-uncss?

Tags: css, gulp, uncss

I'm new to gulp and uncss, and am not sure whether my logic is flawed, or whether what I need is not possible.

I'd like uncss to ignore a slew of CSS rules that are prefixed with a certain string, but that have many compound selectors chained in their declaration.

I know we can use a regex in our `ignore` statement, and I'm using a regex to hopefully ignore all rules that begin with my prefix. But I'm not sure whether that regex in ignore covers just one class within a selector, or the entire rule.

e.g. I wish for gulp-uncss to ignore all CSS rules that are prefixed with .foo

```
.foo .bar {...}
.foo-baz {...}
.foo-ballz .bazzie:hover {...}
```

And my gulp-uncss rule (that doesn't seem to work as intended)

```
.pipe(uncss({
     html: ['index.html'],
     ignore: ['/^.foo/']
}))
```

Things compile ok, but I seem to be losing some (but not all) needed CSS. Anything I may have missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think I solved my own problem. In our ignore statements, I found you don't have to wrap the regular expression in quotes.

Therefore:

```
.pipe(uncss({
     html: ['index.html'],
     ignore: [/^\.foo/]
}))
```

Seems to be working out ok for me!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use an ignore comment just before your selector:

```
/* uncss:ignore */
```

But, I do prefer your answer. I was wrestling with the same issue and came across yours here.